# How to mock an interface implementing ChannelFactory

Tags: mocking, nunit, channelfactory

This is the method i used to call my wcf service method(GetCountry) through interface IService1.Which implement channel factory

```
public IList<Country> GetCountry()
{
   ChannelFactory<ServiceLibrary.IService1> channelFactory = new               ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);

   IService1 channel1 = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

   var response= channel1.GetCountry();

   return response;
}
```

How to mock the service call using NUNIT?

Answer (score 1):

you cant mock directly . Use any mocking framework and Isolate the service call and get the result of service by some dummy values
Isolate.whencalled.willReturn(serviceValue)

Comment: we are currently using moq framework...is it possible to do with moq

Comment: any solution using moq